# How to mock a function when using QTest?

Tags: python, pyqt, mocking

It appears it is impossible to mock functions with unittest.mock when using QTest to simulate button clicks. I have not been able to figure out why this the case but it has something to do with QTest.mouseClick not knowing that I am mocking the object or perhaps it is mocking my mock.

Here is a minimal example:

```
from PyQt5.QtTest import QTest
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def test_add_item_calls_open_popup():
    main_window = MainWindow()
    
    mock_open_popup = MagicMock()
    main_window._open_popup = mock_open_popup
    
    QTest.mouseClick(main_window.add_item_button, Qt.LeftButton)
    
    mock_open_popup.assert_called_once()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.add_item_button = QPushButton("Add Item")
        self.add_item_button.clicked.connect(self._open_popup) 
    
    def _open_popup(self):
        pass
```

The result is that `_open_popup` is called but not the `mock_open_popup`.

Is there any other way to mock functions? What are my other options when trying to test button clicks?